# Move THREE.Mesh and THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject

Tags: three.js

Code is a little modified version of webgl interactive draggable cubes

5 meshes is created with `new THREE.Mesh` (red) and 5 with `new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject` (blue)

[sorry, example deleted]

Please try to drag them, red and blue cubes moves differently.

Red cube moving is related to the mouse (screen) if I drag one cube to the left, cube moves to the left.
Blue cube moving is related to the ??rotated coordinate system (or camera rotation)?? , if i drag one cube to the left, cube can move up or down and faster than mouse.

I assume it is because `createMultiMaterialObject` is a group of THREE.Mesh with the same geometry and different materials. Anyway I can't see a reason. Why they move differently?

How to make red and blue cubes behave equally `onDocumentMouseMove`?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to explain the "move differently" part. Both in Firefox and Chrome I see them rotating, translating and scaling as expected.

Comment: The effect you are describing is perspective projection. If I understand what you want, try an orthographic camera.

Comment: I tried orthographic  camera, anyway red and blue cubes change position differently when I drag one of them. Sorry for my english. Can it be related to the object nesting? When I create cube with THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject mesh is added to the group, nesting is deeper.

Comment: I just realized your problem. You mean when you pick a cube with the mouse and you move it you observe different behaviors. I was just clicking in the background and the behavior I saw was the same. I will have to study your code a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks gaitat, I just found solution, it is because of deeper nesting, when cube is created with THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject SELECTED.position is always (0,0,0). Changed to SELECTED.parent.position and INTERSECTED.parent.position.